# Insert array into hashmap without creating a new array

Tags: java, arrays, insert, hashmap

I want to insert array into hashmap. When val of Integer type is created then I put to map is perfectly fine.

```
Integer[] val = {1,2};

LinkedHashMap<String, Integer[]> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer[]>();
map.put("1", val);
```

But when I don't want to create a array and insert directly into map like this below

```
map.put("1", {1,2});
```

then its not correct. Why ? 
How this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do:

```
map.put("1", new Integer[] {1,2});
```

which is allowing to insert anonymous arrays in the map

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the instance of `Integer[]`, where as `{1,2}` isn't an `Integer[]` instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
Integer[] val = {1, 2};
```

then `{1, 2}` is an *array initializer*. This can only be used in a declaration of an array variable, not in any other places.

ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ has already told you the syntax you can use instead: `new Integer[] {1, 2}`. This works everywhere you can use an array. I figure they thought that you should be forced to use the `new` keyword when you allocate a new array, and then made the exception when you do it as part of the declaration.